# How to animate back my buttons

Tags: javascript, jquery, button, jquery-animate

A small problem... I think!
I have a menu of buttons. When one clicked, it moves (animates). When another one is clicked, I need the first one to move back again.
So far they only moves when clicked, but not back again. 
The code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var vari = $(this).attr('name');
    $('.nav_btn').click(function(){
  $(this).animate({left:'50%'});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this use `.siblings()` here:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var vari = $(this).attr('name');
    $('.nav_btn').click(function(){
        $(this).animate({left:'50%'});
        $(this).siblings().animate({left: '0'});
    });
});
```

### [Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/JYCtF/)

Although not required but you can provide a `animation duration` of animate.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery, this seems easy to me. What you do is, that you give all buttons same className and you loop through all of them when one of them is clicked. Because you can get element collection this will look much like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var vari = $(this).attr('name');

  $('.nav_btn').click(function(){
     var buttons = $('.nav_btn');
     for(var i=0; i<buttons.length; i++) {
         if(buttons[i]!=this)         //Avoid animating clicked button twice! Think of performance
           $(buttons[i].animate({left:'0%'});
     }
     $(this).animate({left:'50%'});
  });
});
```